# User Key pairs and Man-in-the-middle issues

Tags: man-in-the-middle, key-management, key-exchange

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to exchange user's keys with a server.

Maybe during sign-up a JS applet generates a key-pair for the user.  These keys would be used for signing subsequent requests from the user to the server, so the server needs a copy of the users' public key to associate with that user's account.

But sending the public key to the server is subject to MITM attacks - if a sufficiently motivated bad guy wanted to he could put himself in the middle, capture the public key on its way to the server and substitute with a key for which he controls the secret key.

Part of the solution seems to be to have the agent submit the public key only via an encrypted channel, eg TLS.  But it seems that with browser based applications, the onus is still very much on the user to be both educated and awake enough to realize when their session is not with the right server that he aught to be connected to.  In particular our motivated bad guy could set up something that appears authentic and credible, eg

`httpS://certificate_server_acme.com`

which he would be in control of.  Our user may not realize he SHOULD be connecting only to, eg, `httpS://certificates.acme.com`

I suspect that this is just a case of "self-signed certificates".  Passwords doesn't solve the issue.  Verifying a user's key by means of an email message is not viable unless users can compare and verify a key and our motivated bad guy cannot tamper with email messages on the way to the user.

Or is there something, maybe a feature of OpenID, that can be used?

Answer (score 2):

There is already an infrastructure to manage trust and it's called "Public Key Infrastructure". This is the basis of all the SSL/TLS protocols used over the internet and websites.

The main idea is to designate a Trusted Third Party (TTP) which is recognised by all the parties involved. These TTP issues their public key and they are shipped by default in all major browsers (we have to assume there is no tampering before this point, or the all thing fails). Once you have that public key that you trust with no doubt, any server can ask the TTP (which is called a Certificate Authority) to deliver them a certificate. The certificate includes a public key and the identity of the certificate requester and the certificate issuer. When the CA verified the identity of the requester, the certificate is signed by the private key of the CA.

Anyone who gets this signed certificate can verify the CA signature. If it's ok, you deduce that the certificate (therefore the public key) belongs to the entity mentioned in the certificate. You can then use it to encrypt message to this person without fear of it being intercepted by someone else.

If someone where to make a MitM attack on the system he would need to :

- get a forged certificate for a domain name he does not own
- get the victim to accept a new/fake CA certificate on which he has control (and then generate forged certificate)
- break the public key (very unlikely)

Otherwise, the certificate signature would not be verified and therefore the authenticity of the public key would not be proven.

Comment: What about personal certificates / Key pairs?

Comment: Well, as I say, you have to decide on a common Trusted (Third) Party from which you can reliably get a public key. If you can have this (whether it's an official CA, or your own) you can make the PKI works. Otherwise, you will have problem with MitM attacks.

Comment: The problem remains.  If the server trusts only some PKI, then that becomes a limiting factor for user adoption.  I should have explained that this is for an "open to the public" situation, not in-house corporate where the users and their personal keys can be enforced to a specific PKI service.

Comment: This is not a limiting factor. In the case of HTTPS, a website trusts a single CA, while client browsers trust multiple CAs (as you can see if you take time to explore the list of root certificate on your machine). As a server/website, you just have to choose to trust a CA that is already in that list of client-trusted-CAs. Of course if you are running your own CA, you have to make the clients accept it as trusted.

Comment: Either there is something huge that I am not aware of (Eg users can with zero or near zero interaction obtain a personal certificate from a CA), or you don't understand my issue.

Comment: A user connecting to an TLS enabled website does not need anything (except the root CA certificate embedded in the browser) to validate the authenticity of the website's certificate. Then the client can start a secured communication with the website. Once you have a secure channel, you are free to exchange anything you want (a user key or whatever you need to).

Comment: But the problem is that the server doesn't know who is talking to it at that point.

Comment: Indeed. To do that you need either a client certificate from the CA (user has to do that himself), or you have to find a way to authenticate a user and give him a key/certificate you generated yourself for him. You can't magically authenticate a random client.

Comment: Even if I "authenticate a user" I have no way of knowing whether that user is actually signed in into my web site (connected to my server directly) or is in fact connected to a malicious MITM who forwarded the authentication data "on behalf of the user".  So I can generate a key pair for him, or better: provide some way for him to generate the key pair so that only the pubic key need to be transited, but since the server accepts ANY RANDOM CONNECTION, the server won't know whether that key has been compromised or not.

Comment: Even if I do make the user sign up for and get a certificate from a "Trusted CA" the "sufficiently motivated" MITM could still intercept that key, register another key for which they will have access to the secret/private half, and continue to intercept all communications, modify the requests and responses, and even impostor the end user.

Comment: Well, the idea of using a "Trusted" Third Party is to have this TTP issue certificate only to the real person. If I cannot provide an identification as Mr X, the TTP will not give me a certificate stating I am Mr X. If the CA operates according to this standard, there is no more MitM possible. The owner of the certificate has the only copy of the private key, only he can decrypt message coded with his certificate's public key.

Comment: Most CAs accept that, for individual/personal certificates, you are who you say you are.  The only thing the cert proves is that the Email address supplied to the CA was in fact used by who-ever operated the system. And that assumes that email was not compromised.  CAs make an effort to ensure that a real human is behind the request for a certificate, but CAPCHA is not infallible. During the sign-up process the motivated MITM could substitute the email address from the real user with the one used to obtain the certificate.

Comment: You have to find a TTP that does what you need. And with a "motivated MITM" you can basically devise any scenario you want (one that would compromise the CA for example). Security is a trade-off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22128/discussion-between-mvy-and-johan).